# how to get rid of #011 characters in java

Tags: java

I am getting this string while I got the content over JMSQ. While printing I see the following line. I see those are vertical tab characters in XML. But how should I get rid of them.

```
       #011#011#011<xeh:eid>dljfl</xeh:eid>
```

I have tried

```
       replaceAll("[\\x0B]", "");
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Yes, it is java string

Comment: Have you considered `a.replaceAll("#011", "")`?

Comment: I have made more edits.

Comment: `replaceAll("#011", "");`

Comment: I will try a.replaceAll("#011", "") and let you know.

Comment: #011 is  a single char, I see it while getting printed using System.out.println, I am not sure what should we use while replacing should we use #011, or something else, any ways I am trying using replaceAll("#011", "")

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @naren can you create a hex-dump of the (sub)string, so we can clearly see which character you mean? (For example with `Arrays.toString("...".getBytes("UTF-8"))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When #011 represents the hexvalue for the char you can use

```
a.replaceAll("\\u0011", "");
// or
a.replaceAll("\\x11", "");
```

But if #011 represents the octal value the use

```
a.replaceAll("\\011", "")
```

Also see [Unicode Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: You are right boss, I am getting octal value, and so far I am trying thinking it as decimal. Thank you, now it's working a.replaceAll("\\011", "")

Answer (score 2):

`"#011#011#011<xeh:eid>dljfl</xeh:eid>".replaceAll("#011", "")` works fine, results in `<xeh:eid>dljfl</xeh:eid>`

According to the [Pattern javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\xhh` stands for "the character with hexadecimal value 0xhh". But I guess in your string literal, `#011` is just literal characters.

---

If I try to replicate the vertical tab in a string literal, it works with `\\x0B`:

```
"\u000b\u000b\u000b<xeh:eid>dljfl</xeh:eid>".replaceAll("\\x0B", "")
```

But maybe we are reading it wrong. While #0B is 11, #11 might be 17...

Comment: no, I am pasting the same comment as I did for the above post, I did not mean literally #011 in string, I have modified the question. #011 are 4 characters, but what we are seeing while printing is one character with ascii value 11 and that is vertical tab, we need to replace it, those who are downvotying un-necessarily should think about this.

Comment: @naren Then you need to explain us what you mean by printing. When I use `System.out.println(a.replaceAll("#011", ""))`, it correctly removes the sequences. What's different on your end.

Comment: No, I am getting message over JMS, and when I print the message I see those #011 characters, If you have them assigned to a string explicitly then those are 4 characters # 0 1 1, I believe #011 is a single char which represents vertical tab in an xml which I got.

Comment: Now I got it. So that string is not a string literal. K, have you tried `"\\x0B"` instead of `"[\\x0B]"`?

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
    String a = "#011#011#011<xeh:eid>dljfl</xeh:eid>";
    String a_wo_vt_chars = a.replaceAll("#011", "");
```

Comment: This did not work at all, I did not mean literally #011 in string, I have modified the question. #011 are 4 characters, but what we are seeing while printing is one character with ascii value 11 and that is vertical tab, we need to replace it, those who are downvotying un-necessarily should think about this.

Comment: Maybe they are downvoting because you did not provide the necessary informations in the first place.

Comment: Ok, will keep that in mind and provide valid information at the first place from now onwards.